# How to plot visualization with Interactive Feature Selection in Bokeh, Python

Tags: python, visualization, data-analysis, bokeh

The task is to automate the Visualization. The CSV file contains large nos of features (column names e:g. 32 nos it may increase in future). The task is to plot Interactive Visualization. All the examples I found are hardcoded for the dynamic features selection.

But the requirement is to make the stuff dynamic. How to make it dynamic? Please guide.

I have successfully plotted the graph dynamically, but could not connect the interactive part. The code is as follows:

```
    import pandas as pd
    from bokeh.plotting import figure
    from bokeh.io import show
    from bokeh.models import CustomJS,HoverTool,ColumnDataSource,Select
    from bokeh.models.widgets import CheckboxGroup
    from bokeh.models.annotations import Title, Legend
    import itertools
    from bokeh.palettes import inferno
    from bokeh.layouts import row
    
    def creat_plot(dataframe):
        data=dataframe
        #Converting the timestamp Column to Timestamp datatype so that it can be used for Plotting on X-axis
        data['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(data['timestamp'])
        
        #Segregating Date and Time from timestamp column. It will be used in Hover Tool
        date = lambda x: str(x)[:10]
        data['date'] = data[['timestamp']].applymap(date)
        time= lambda x: str(x)[11:]
        data['time'] = data[['timestamp']].applymap(time)
        
        #Converting whole dataframe ColumnDatasource for easy usage in hover tool
        source = ColumnDataSource(data)
        
        # List all the tools that you want in your plot separated by comas, all in one string.
        TOOLS="crosshair,pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,hover"
        
        # New figure
        t = figure(x_axis_type = "datetime", width=1500, height=600,tools=TOOLS,title="Plot for Interactive Features")
        
        #X-axis Legend Formatter
        t.xaxis.formatter.days = '%d/%m/%Y'
        
        #Axis Labels
        t.yaxis.axis_label = 'Count'
        t.xaxis.axis_label = 'Date and Time Span'
        
        #Grid Line Formatter
        t.ygrid.minor_grid_line_color = 'navy'
        t.ygrid.minor_grid_line_alpha = 0.1
        t.xgrid.visible = True
        t.ygrid.visible= True
        
        #Hover Tool Usage
        t.select_one(HoverTool).tooltips = [('Date', '@date'),('Time', '@time')]
        
        #A color iterator creation
        colors = itertools.cycle(inferno(len(data.columns)))
        
        #A Line type iterator creation
        line_types= ['solid','dashed','dotted','dotdash','dashdot']
        lines= itertools.cycle(line_types)
        
        column_name=[]
        #Looping over the columns to plot the Data
        for m in data.columns[2:len(data.columns)-2]:
            column_name.append(m)
            a=t.line(data.columns[0], m ,color=next(colors),source=source,line_dash=next(lines), alpha= 1)
         
        #Adding Label Selection Check Box List
        column_name= list(column_name)
        checkboxes = CheckboxGroup(labels = column_name, active= [0,1,2])
        
        #callback= CustomJS(code=code,args=dict(source=source))
        #checkboxes.js_on_click(callback)
        show(row(t,checkboxes))
```

The above function can be used as follows:

```
dataframe= pd.read_csv('data.csv')
creat_plot(dataframe)
```

**The above code is executed on following requirements:

1. Bokeh version: 2.2.3
2. Panda Version: 1.1.3

The portion I need help is #callback= CustomJS(code=code,args=dict(source=source)). The code need to be dynamic. Please guide.

[image]